# Difference using pointer in struct fields

Tags: pointers, go, struct

We can create structs in golang this way. Examples below:
What are differences between these two?

```
// Usual way
type Employee struct {
    firstName string    `json:"name"`
    salary    int       `json:"salary"`
    fullTime  bool      `json:"fullTime"`
    projects  []Project `json:"projects"`
}

// Un-usal way with pointers
type Employee struct {
    firstName *string    `json:"name"`
    salary    *int       `json:"salary"`
    fullTime  *bool      `json:"fullTime"`
    projects  *[]Project `json:"projects"`
}
```

Are there any trade-offs like memory?

**Update:**

Assume below function:

```
// this function consumes MORE memory
func printEmployeeWithoutPointer(employee Employee) {
    // print here
}

// this function consumes LESS memory
func printEmployeeWithPointer(employee *Employee) {
    // print here
}
```

Comment: The difference is exactly the same as the general difference between a pointer and a non-pointer. Are you asking the implications of using a pointer?

Comment: @mkopriva agree with you, I tried compiling and searched all over docs but couldn't find this unusual way.

Comment: Using pointers always requires more memory. E.g. having an `int32` is just 4 bytes, while working with `*int32` is 4 bytes + size of pointer (which may be 4 or 8 bytes). Again, what are you asking, what are you interested in?

Comment: My idea is to consume less memory when decoding data from rest api.
Should I use Employee struct with pointers to hold Array of employees.

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov No, don't use pointers unless you really REALLY need to share data

Comment: All employees will be (should be?) unique, storing the data in pointer will use more memory since you will store the data and a pointer to the data

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov thanks for updating your question, it is quite clear now.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right, there's a number of things to consider. First up: let's start with the obvious syntax error in your pointer example:

```
type Employee struct {
    FirstName *string `json:"name"`
    Salary    *int    `json:"salary"`
    FullTime  *bool   `json:"fullTime"`
}
```

So I've moved the asterisk to the type, and I've captialized the fields. The `encoding/json` package uses reflection to set the values of the fields, so they need to be exported.

Seeing as you're using json tags, let's start with the simple things:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string  `json:"bar"`
    Foo *string `json:"foo,omitempty"`
}
```

When I'm unmarshalling a message that has no `bar` value, the `Bar` field will just be an empty string. That makes it kind of hard to work out whether or not the field was sent or not. Especially when dealing with integers: how do I tell the difference between a field that wasn't sent vs a field that was sent with a value of 0?
Using a pointer field, and specify `omitempty` allows you to do that. If the field wasn't specified in the JSON data, then the field in your struct will be `nil`, if not: it'll point to an integer of value 0.

Of course, having to check for pointers being nil can be tedious, it makes code more error-prone, and so you only need to do so if there's an actual reason why you'd want to differentiate between a field not being set, and a zero value.

---

## pitfalls

### Pointers allow you to change values of what they point to

Let's move on to the risks pointers inherently bring with them. Assuming your `Employee` struct with pointer fields, and a type called `EmployeeV` that is the same but with value fields, consider these functions:

```
func (e Employee) SetName(name string) {
    if e.Firstname == nil {
        e.Firstname = &name
        return
    }
    *e.Firstname = name
}
```

Now this function is only going to work half of the time. You're calling `SetName` on a value receiver. If `Firstname` is nil, then you're going to set the pointer on a copy of your original variable, and your variable will not reflect the change you made in the function. If `Firstname` *was* set, however, the copy will point to the same string as your original variable, and the value that pointer points to *will* get updated. That's bad.

Implement the same function on `EmployeeV`, however:

```
func (e EmployeeV) SetName(name string) {
    e.Firstname = name
}
```

And it simply won't *ever* work. You'll always update a copy, and the changes won't affect the variable on which you call the `SetName` function. For that reason, the idiomatic way, in go, to do something like this would be:

```
type Employee struct {
    Firstname string
    // other fields
}

func (e *Employee) SetName(name string) {
    e.Firstname = name
}
```

So we're changing the *method* to use a pointer receiver.

### Data races

As always: if you're using pointers, you're essentially allowing code to manipulate the memory something points to directly. Given how golang is a language that is known to facilitate concurrency, and accessing the same bit of memory means you're at risk of creating data-races:

```
func main() {
    n := "name"
    e := Employee{
        Firstname: &n,
    }
    go func() {
         *e.Firstname = "foo"
    }()
    race(e)
}

func race(e Employee) {
    go race(e)
    go func() {
        *e.Firstname = "in routine"
    }()
    *e.Firstname = fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().UnixNano())
}
```

This `Firstname` field is accessed in a lot of different routines. What will be its eventual value? Do you even know? The golang race detector will most likely flag this code as a potential data race.

---

In terms of memory use: individual fields like ints or bools really aren't the thing you ought to be worried about. If you're passing around a sizeable struct, and you know it's safe, then it's probably a good idea to pass around a pointer to said struct. Then again, accessing values through a pointer rather than accessing them directly isn't free: indirection adds a small overhead.

Answer (score 17):

We use pointers **to share data**, but that doesn't always mean it is more memory efficient or more performant. Go is extremely good and fast at copying data.

When it comes to structs a common reason for using pointers is that pointers can have `nil` values, where primitives can't. **If you need a struct with optionals field, you'd use pointers**

If you are deserialising JSON then you could omit fields using `omitempty`. Here fullTime is optional

```
type Employee struct {
    firstName string `json:"name"`
    salary int `json:"salary"`
    fullTime *bool `json:"fullTime,omitempty"`
}
```

**Performance when using JSON**

If you are deserializing JSON into pointers in the hopes of saving memory, you won't. From a JSON point of view each item is unique, so there is no sharing of data. You will use more memory, because each value now has to  store a value and a pointer to the value. And it will be slower because you will need to dereference pointers the whole time

Comment: I have updated Employee struct by adding projects field.
In pointer version it hold reference to the array, but in non-pointer version it holds all projects. If the projects are very large (1000000), will it consume more memory when passing Employee to another function?

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov Is the project data shared or does it come from JSON?

Comment: It comes from JSON, rest api

Comment: Then my answer stands, a pointer will actually make performance worse

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov slices are headers with a pointer to the underlying array and the len and cap info (https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals). Do not use poniters to slices for memory efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, additional reading https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#pass-values .

Pass Values
Don't pass pointers as function arguments just to save a few bytes. If a function refers to its argument x only as *x throughout, then the argument shouldn't be a pointer. Common instances of this include passing a pointer to a string (*string) or a pointer to an interface value (*io.Reader). In both cases the value itself is a fixed size and can be passed directly. This advice does not apply to large structs, or even small structs that might grow.