# How to properly append pointer type elements in a many to many relationship in golang gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

### Summary

I defined a 'UserFollowing' as a 'struct' type

```
type UserFollowing struct {
    ID         string `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;unique" json:"id"`
    User       User   `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:UserId"`
    Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:UserId;JoinReferences:following_id"`
}
```

Where type 'User' is defined as

```
type User struct {
    Email                 string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"email"`
    Password              string          `gorm:"size:60;not null" json:"password,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"updated_at"`
    Verified              bool            `gorm:"default:false" json:"verified"`
    AToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"accessToken"`
    RToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"refreshToken"`
    YouAreFollowing       bool            `json:"youAreFollowing"`
    Username              string          `json:"username"`
    Online                bool            `json:"online"`
    NumFollowing          uint64          `json:"numFollowing"`
    NumFollowers          uint64          `json:"numFollowers"`
    LastOnline            time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"lastOnline"`
    UserId                string          `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;unique" json:"userid"`
    FollowsYou            bool            `json:"followsYou"`
    BotOwnerId            string          `json:"botOwnerId"`
    Contributions         uint64          `json:"contributions"`
    Staff                 bool            `json:"staff"`
    DisplayName           string          `gorm:"size:20" json:"displayName"`
    CurrentRoomId         string          `json:"currentRoomId"`
    CurrentRoom           Room            `json:"currentRoom"`
    Bio                   string          `gorm:"size:250" json:"bio"`
    Avatar                string          `gorm:"size:100" json:"avatarUrl"`
    BannerUrl             string          `json:"bannerUrl"`
    WhisperPrivacySetting string          `json:"whisperPrivacySetting"`
    Room_Permissions      RoomPermissions `json:"roomPermissions"`
}
```

I tried to append 'User' type elements to the 'Followings' field by doing the following:

```
for i, _ := range users {
        ...
        userfollowings[i].ID = users[i].UserId
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, users[i])
        ...
        
    }
```

### Error

```
cannot use users[i] (type models.User) as type *models.User in append
```

### Unsuccessful Attempt

```
        *userfollowings[i].Followings = append(*userfollowings[i].Followings, users[i])
```

### References consulted

[difference-using-pointer-in-struct-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964619/difference-using-pointer-in-struct-fields)
Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use address of the structure instead of direct value if you want to store pointers []*User.

Try to visit [this page](https://go.dev/play/p/1FIeDiGJt5t) and run this code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    UserId string
}

type UserFollowing struct {
    ID         string
    Followings []*User
}

var (
    users          = []User{{"user-1"}, {"user-2"}, {"user-3"}}
    userFollowings = make([]UserFollowing, len(users))
)

func main() {

    for i, _ := range users {
        // ...
        userFollowings[i].ID = users[i].UserId
        userFollowings[i].Followings = append(userFollowings[i].Followings, &users[i])
        // ...
    }
    fmt.Println("%#v", userFollowings)
}
```